# Is the products of all primes less than $n$ greater than $n$? Proof check

Tags: inequality, prime-numbers

Let $p_1, p_2, ..., p_k$ be the prime numbers less than $n$, prove that their products are greater than $n$.

**My attempt**

Let $P=p_1 \cdot p_2 \cdot ... \cdot p_k$ be the product. Since $P-1$ is not divisible by all the prime numbers less than $n$, $P-1$ must be divisible by some prime number greater than or equal to $n$. So $P-1$ is greater than or equal to $n$. Hence $P$ is greater than $n$.

Comment: You maybe need to specify $n>1$ but the proof looks good to me.

Comment: The logic is good, but some of the phrasing could be improved.  I think you mean to say that $P-1$ is not divisible "by *any* of the primes less than $n$", not "by *all* of the primes less than $n$"

Comment: You need $n >3$.